# Why spring have mandatory logging dependency?

Tags: java, spring, logging

I search about logger in java,purpose is check application, send messages in runtime,allows us to know some informaton what is happening in some part in our app.
But i don t know why it for spring is logger mandatory?

Can anyone explain to me?

Comment: You can disable logging, it just needs something on the classpath conforming to commons-logging's interface.

Answer (score 1):

Taken from this blog here https://spring.io/blog/2009/12/04/logging-dependencies-in-spring/

> Logging is a very important dependency for Spring because
>
> a) it is the
> only mandatory external dependency,
>
> b) everyone likes to see some
> output from the tools they are using, and
>
> c) Spring integrates with
> lots of other tools all of which have also made a choice of logging
> dependency. One of the goals of an application developer is often to
> have unified logging configured in a central place for the whole
> application, including all external components. This is more difficult
> than it might have been since there are so many choices of logging
> framework.